# About the Gettysburg Address

Tags: grammar, semantics

I have two questions regarding the Gettysburg Address.

1) **Double That**

> We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live.

Actually a double that isn't a problem. I am just wondering whether "so" is omitted before them. This is how I understand this line:

> We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives **so that** **the** nation might live.

I believe that should be the one that has to be omitted. I can understand what it means but it still baffles me.

2) **Meaning of word "Government"**

the most famous line of the address,

> that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth

what does the word "government" indicate here? A governing body or political system?

I've learned that if the word "government" is used with zero-article, it means the political system of governing people while it means a government body when followed by an article.

However, I found that this rule is not always followed. I have seen articles or people saying it without the article even when they mean a government as a governing body.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This should really be split into two questions. Both sections are answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first can be rewritten as *"...who here gave their lives so that the previously-mentioned nation might live"*.  In other words, the first *"that"* is a contraction of *"so that"* and the second means *"the previously-mentioned"*.  I agree that putting them next to each other is awkward but it's the sort of thing which might work fine when heard (which is the objective of a speech, after all), and only looks wrong when you see it written down.

In the second part, i believe *"government of"* means *"the process of governing"*, ie the verb rather than the noun.  You could replace *"government"* with *"organising"* to get a sense of the syntax.